# how to add user and give root permission with python script

Tags: python, ubuntu, permissions

I want to add user on Ubuntu and give root permission with python script
but I don't know how to give permission (root access).

Here is what I have so far:

```
import os
import crypt

username=raw_input("select username:")
password=raw_input("select password:")
mcrypt=crypt.crypt(password,"123")
os.system("sudo useradd -m -p"+password+" "+username)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the user to the `sudo` group.

Here is what you must add to your python script:

```
os.system("sudo usermod -a -G sudo "+username)
```